Como obtengo los APDU para que mi token firme digitalmente un archivo enviado como byte [] en Java con javax.smartcard.io
Tengo un dispositivo token del fabricante Giesecke & Devrient : https://ccid.apdu.fr/ccid/img/GnD_StarSign_CUT.gif
Y estoy haciendo una aplicación que le de la instrucción al token de que me firme archivos mediante su protocolo de comunicación que es : APDU, el código a continuación compila y crea el documento pero no le esta imprimiendo la firma, esto se debe a que no se como pasarle  el archivo, alguien sabe como debería ser al APDU que debo enviarle para que me firme el archivo ? He buscado en internet y no encuentro ninguna lista de APDU para este fabricante.
package javaapplication9;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import javax.smartcardio.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.Loader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

/**
 *
 * @author RichardEduardoViquez
 */
public class JavaApplication9 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        try {
            // Definir el comando APDU para seleccionar la aplicación (applet) en la tarjeta inteligente
            byte[] command = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};

           
            
//            byte[] apduBytes = {
//                (byte) 0x00, // CLA (Class byte)
//                (byte) 0x2A, // INS (Instruction byte para solicitar firma digital)
//                (byte) 0x9E, // P1 (Parameter 1)
//                (byte) 0x00, // P2 (Parameter 2)
//                (byte) fileBytes.length // Lc (Length of Command Data) - longitud de los datos del archivo
//            };
//
//            // Concatenar los bytes del archivo al comando APDU
//            byte[] fullApdu = new byte[apduBytes.length + fileBytes.length];
//            System.arraycopy(apduBytes, 0, fullApdu, 0, apduBytes.length);
//            System.arraycopy(fileBytes, 0, fullApdu, apduBytes.length, fileBytes.length);
//
//            // Transmitir el comando APDU con los datos del archivo al token
//            ResponseAPDU response = card.getBasicChannel().transmit(new CommandAPDU(fullApdu));

            List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
            if (terminals.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No se detectaron lectores de tarjetas inteligentes.");
                return;
            }

            // Seleccionar el primer lector de tarjetas inteligentes disponible
            CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(1);

            // Conectar a la tarjeta inteligente
            Card card = terminal.connect("*");
            System.out.println("Tarjeta conectada: " + card);

            byte[] ATRS = card.getATR().getBytes();
            int cla = ATRS[0]; // Extract CLA byte
            System.out.println("CLA: " + cla);
            System.out.println("Tarjeta conectada: " + ATRS);

            ResponseAPDU responseSelectApplet = card.getBasicChannel().transmit(new CommandAPDU(command));
            if (responseSelectApplet.getSW1() == 0x90 && responseSelectApplet.getSW2() == 0x00) {
                byte[] aidBytes = responseSelectApplet.getData();
                System.out.println("AID: " + bytesToHex(aidBytes));
            } else {
                System.out.println("No se pudo obtener el AID.");
            }

            //Leer el contenido del archivo que deseas firmar
            byte[] fileData = readFile("xxxxxload.pdf");
            
            
              //Definir el comando APDU para solicitar la firma del documento
            byte[] apduBytes = {
                (byte) 0x59, // CLA (Class byte)
                (byte) 0x2A, // INS (Instruction byte para solicitar firma digital)
                (byte) 0x9E, // P1 (Parameter 1)
                (byte) 0x00, // P2 (Parameter 2)
                (byte) fileData.length // Lc (Length of Command Data) - no hay datos adicionales
            };

          
//            byte[] fullApdu = new byte[apduBytes.length + fileData.length];
//            System.arraycopy(apduBytes, 0, fullApdu, 0, apduBytes.length);
//            System.arraycopy(fileData, 0, fullApdu, apduBytes.length, fileData.length);
            
            
            //byte[] commandData = prepareCommandData(fileData);
            //Enviar el comando APDU al token USB
            //CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
            ResponseAPDU response = card.getBasicChannel().transmit(new CommandAPDU(apduBytes));

            // Procesar la respuesta del token USB
            byte[] signature = response.getData();
            System.out.println("firma " + signature);
            // Guardar la firma en un archivo
            saveFile("xxxxxdownload.pdf", "xxxxxxdownload-signed.pdf", signature);

            // Desconectar el token USB
            card.disconnect(true);

            System.out.println("Firma digital generada por la tarjeta inteligente: " + signature);
            // Desconectar de la tarjeta inteligente
            card.disconnect(false);
            System.out.println("Tarjeta desconectada.");
        } catch (CardException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }

    private static void saveFile(String filePath, String fileSave, byte[] data) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(file)) {
            document.addPage(page);
            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
                contentStream.appendRawCommands("Firma Digital:");
                contentStream.newLine();
                contentStream.appendRawCommands(new String(data));
                contentStream.endText();
            }

            document.save(fileSave);
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    private static byte[] readFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File(filePath))) {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String text = stripper.getText(document);
            return text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }

}

